# Efficiently Modifying CGColor

Tags: iphone, performance, objective-c++, cgcolor

I have an iPhone app where I'm "adding" a lot of CGColors together by breaking them down into their components, averaging the components, and then making a new color with the new components. When I run this code, Instruments finds that I'm leaking lots of CGColors, and the app runs slowly.

I feel like I could solve the memory leak issue if there were a way to do what I'm doing without using CGColorCreate(colorspace, components) every time.

This is the code for the color "adding"

```
const CGFloat *cs=CGColorGetComponents(drawColor);
const CGFloat *csA=CGColorGetComponents(add->drawColor);
CGFloat r=(cs[0]*w+csA[0]*aW)/1;
CGFloat g=(cs[1]*w+csA[1]*aW)/1;
CGFloat b=(cs[2]*w+csA[2]*aW)/1;
CGFloat components[]={r, g, b, 1.f};
drawColor=CGColorCreate(CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), components);
```

Any help would be really appreciated, even if the help is "add the colors less often." I'm sure I'm not the only person trying to modify CGColors.

EDIT: So, rob's comment put me on the right track, but I'm getting malloc double free errors because the method with the color adding is called multiple times before a new drawColor is assigned. Is there a way to check whether drawColor exists before I release it? Here is the new relevant code.

```
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace=CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGColorRelease(drawColor);
drawColor=CGColorCreate(colorSpace, components);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're leaking `CGColor` objects, the first step to solving your problem is to stop leaking them.  You need to call `CGColorRelease` when you're done with a color object.  For example, you are obviously leaking the `drawColor` object in your example code.  You should be doing this:

```
CGColorRelease(drawColor);
drawColor=CGColorCreate(CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), components);
```

to release the old object referenced by `drawColor` before you assign the new object to `drawColor`.

`CGColor` objects are immutable, so you won't be able to just modify your existing objects.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am releasing the CGColor after I assign it to the context with CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, color). That would accomplish the same thing, wouldnt it? I can't test your suggestion now but I will later.

Comment: I don't think I can edit a comment, but you are right. I'm leaking colors because the method that assigns drawColor happens more frequently than drawRect: where I release the color. Thanks for pointing that out; I'm going to test it when I get the chance.

Comment: Regardless of whether or not you or anyone has an answer to my edited question, I found a place to put my CGColorReleases. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4):

Pretty sure you just need to `CGColorRelease(drawColor)` to prevent the leak. See how that helps your performance.

Comment: psst! note `CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB` too ;)

Comment: Thanks, Justin. I looked that up and now I'm releasing the CGColorSpaceRef that I was allocating in-line. Is there a way to upvote comments?